Handling out-of-range day of month with DATEFROMPARTS
I'm using DATEFROMPARTS to construct a date using a year and month stored in one table, and a day of the month in another. But I get this error where the day of the month is invalid for that month:
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(2024, 4, 31);


Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.

e.g.
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(a.Year, a.Month, b.Day)
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON a.FK_b = b.Id

One solution is to roll over into the next month, e.g. "April, 31" becomes "May, 01":
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, b.Day - 1, DATEFROMPARTS(a.Year, a.Month, 1))...

How could I clamp the Day parameter to be "Day X, or the last day of the month, whichever is later" e.g. 2024, 4, 31 becomes 2024-04-30?

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-date-functions/sql-server-eomonth-function/

Why are you storing what are, effectively, invalid dates in the first place? This smells like an XY Problem; don't store the date in parts store your date as a date. If you need the parts, JOIN to your calendar table.

I am not storing anything. The schema is not up for discussion.

"I am not storing anything" then the table empty? You won't get the error then. There has to be something stored in the table for you to get the error you state you do.

I am not storing anything. The schema and its contents are not under my control. If you have nothing to add to the question, kindly close the tab, thank you.

"The schema is not up for discussion" but that is the problem. There is no 31 April, so why are you allowing that value to be stored? If you fixed the design the problem literally disappears.

@JackDeeth You will need to check against a calendar table, as Thom A kindly indicated, or use the information Yitzhak Khabinsky linked to.

@JackDeeth How does b.Day get into the database? Is it actually meant to be an indicator for end-of-month rather than the actual day of the end of a month?

It's a scheduling system. b.Day is the day of the month when an event usually happens. a.Year and a.Month are the month when it happens @AndrewMorton. Again, the schema and data within are not under my control, so don't tell me "don't let people schedule things for 31 Apr then", I am painfully aware ¯_(ツ)_/¯

@JackDeeth OK, so do you want to clamp it to the last day of the month or move it into the next month, with regard to the "simple", "better", and "How" parts? It seems to me that if someone chose "31" then it is likely they meant the end of a month, but the application may dictate otherwise.

I suggest JOINing to your Calendar table, as that will have dates in their constitute parts in columns. As, however, you have invalid dates then you can use 2 JOINs to get the date for the 1st of the month, should the 1st JOIN fail, and then add a month to it in the SELECT.
Something like this:
SELECT ISNULL(RD.CalendarDate,DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FD.CalendarDate))
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Calendar RD ON YT.Year = RD.CalenderYear
                              AND YT.Month = RD.CalendarMonth
                              AND YT.Day = RD.CalendarDay
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Calendar FD ON YT.Year = FD.CalenderYear
                              AND FT.Month = FD.CalendarMonth
                              AND FT.CalendarDay = 1

Of course, if you have months like 13 or 0 or years like 20224 you're in for only more "hurt"; fixing the design and/or (at least) adding a CHECK CONSTRAINT so that invalid dates can't be added would be a must then.

Thank you, this looks like it would work wonderfully... if we had a calendar table... thanks anyway!

Then invest the time to create one, @JackDeeth . They are invaluable.

I would if I could. Not sure how much more clearly I can say that the schema is not in my control!

Thanks to Yitzhak Khabinsky for the suggestion. EOMONTH finds the last day of the month for a given day. "Nth day of month or the last day of the month, whichever is earliest" can be found like this:
WITH "EventDateCalc" AS (
    SELECT
        b.Id,
        EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(a.Year, a.Month, 1) AS "MonthEnd",
        DATEADD(DAY, b.Day - 1, DATEFROMPARTS(a.Year, a.Month, 1) AS "Rollover"
    FROM TableA a
    JOIN TableB b ON a.FK_b = b.Id
)
SELECT CASE MonthEnd < Rollover THEN MonthEnd ELSE Rollover AS "EventDate"
FROM EventDateCalc



Better solution: roll over into the next month, e.g. "April, 31" becomes "May, 01"

Well, if you are okay with rolling over, you can roll over the month too:
select
  dateadd(
    d,
    b.Day - 1,
    dateadd(
      year, 
      (a.Month - 1) / 12,
      datefromparts(a.Year, (a.Month - 1) % 12 + 1, 1)
    )
  )

https://dbfiddle.uk/lvHHUEm-
(2000, 42, 42) => 2003-07-12.
